# What does "linking" mean?

Tags: pronunciation, linking

When I am learning about pronunciation of English, I found a word called linking. The word seems about pronunciation.

What is linking? And how can I learn correct linking in pronunciation?

Comment: I added the last question to make it relevant to learning (and on-topic for this site) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of pronunciation, **linking** refers to joining words together so that they sound like a single word. In speech, words are usually not separated by pauses or breaks but are pronounced as a continuous stream of sounds. This is also known as [**connected speech**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_speech) and does not only exist in spoken English.

When two words are pronounced together, they can get "linked" or joined by certain changes in pronunciation.

- Sounds can change, especially in the pronuncation of "to". For example, in "I'm going to buy some milk", the 'o' in 'to' will sounds as a [schwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa) (`/ə/`).
- Two sounds can be pronounced as just one sound. For example, in "He'**s s**lept for 10 hours", you will hear only one 's' in the first part of the sentence.
- Sounds can disappear. For example, "next month" can sound like "nex month" (without the 't' in 'next').
- A sound may be shared between two words. For example, "this afternoon" will sound more link "thi**z**afternoon".
- A linking `/j/` may be added between two vowels, as in "play out" (`/pleɪjaʊt/`).
- A linking `/w/` may be added between two vowels, as in "so exciting" (`/səʊwɪkˈsaɪtɪŋ/`).
- In some varieties of English, a linking 'r' may be introduced. For example, the 'r' in 'car' is not pronounced in British English (when the word is spoken in isolation), but the 'r' is pronounced when it is followed by a vowel: "The ca**r** is coming."

There are many **resources** available to help you learn or improve linking or connected speech. Since there are pronunciation differences between American English and British English (and other varieties of English), you should use resources that cover the variety of English you want to learn.

American English:

- Go Natural English: [The Secret to American English Pronunciation is Linking Words Together](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DbyWWwILz90).
- [Master Spoken English - Connected Speech - Part 01/10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CyU69DRrv8) and several other videos in the same series. (American English).
- Elemental English: [Connected Speech & Linking](http://www.elementalenglish.com/connected-speech-linking-american-english-pronunciation/) and [Connected Speech Practice](http://www.elementalenglish.com/connected-speech-practice-english-pronunciation/).
- Rachel's English: [Linking: Vowel to Vowel -- American Accent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgbKlupt7l8), [Linking: Consonant to Vowel -- American Accent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7tsljuK4f2E) and [Linking Consonant to Consonant -- American English Pronunciation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ziKkSig0jM)

British English:

- Oxford Online English: [Video Lesson – Linking](http://www.oxfordonlineenglish.com/video-lesson-linking-pronunciation) (contains the YouTube video [English Pronunciation - Linking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23waYQrmo6wp) ).
- ELT Training (Jo Gakonga): [Connected Speech - weak forms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=us-j7Ftrrag).
- BBC Learn English: [PRONUNCIATION: The linking /r/](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLprxwzWtc4), [Pronunciation: The intrusive /r/](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCJrFM3hdlg), [PRONUNCIATION: Elision of /t/](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1l4HRaCMdw), [PRONUNCIATION: Assimilation of /t/ and /p/](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_ohrkQmzdQ) and [Pronunciation: Assimilation of /d/ to /g/](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDDV01W20bo) .
- [Speak faster and more naturally with connected speech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-P-Bk-Sm9dY).
- British Accent Fast: [Connected Speech and Word Linking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ET3xffdRxH4).
- Doncaster English / David Williams: [Linking Words](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jg3Zla_71jg): special emphasis on linking 'get' with other words.

Australian English:

- RMIT English Worldwide: [English lesson 19: connected speech sentence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTSIOzGHu-k) .

Other relevant links:

- BBC: Learning English: [Pronunciation tips: connected speech](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/pron/features/connected.shtml): archived content of three radio programmes, with downloadable transcripts and MP3 files.
- Pronuncian.com: [Introduction to Linking](https://pronuncian.com/introduction-to-linking). This article is about American English pronunciation.
- PronunciationTips.com: [Linking](http://pronunciationtips.com/linking.htm).
- Wikipedia: [Linking and intrusive R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_and_intrusive_R).
- (Learn Real English: [Linking Sounds in English](http://learnrealenglish.com/linking-sounds-in-english). (American English))